# Android onClickItem is not working on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am trying to implement `onClick` listener on Android. When I click, I need to get the details of one particular item from the `GridLayoutManager`. The `onClick` works but it is listing all the items from the array list.
The Adapter Class:

```
    public class MoviesGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesGridAdapter.PosterViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Movies> movieItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public MoviesGridAdapter(Context context, List<Movies> movieItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public PosterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movies_poster_grid_view_item, parent, false);
        return new PosterViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PosterViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Movies movies = movieItems.get(position);
        String posterUrlPath = movies.getPosterPath();

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(Constants.MOVIE_POSTER_URL + posterUrlPath).into(holder.poster);

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Title", movies.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("Overview", movies.getOverview());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    public class PosterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView poster;
        final View mView;

        public PosterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            poster = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movies_poster_mv);
        }

    }
    public void setMovies(List<Movies> movies) {
        movieItems.clear();
        movieItems = movies;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

I tried that on `ViewHolder` class as well which extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` with the `getAdapterPosition()` stated in the API. I get the intent to another Activity/Fragment but I am not getting the position of the item clicked rather getting the entire list loaded. Here's the [Github project link](https://github.com/mchapagai/Movies). `ListView` has `OnItemClickListner` or `ArrayAdapter`, `RecyclerView` lacks the functionality.

Thank you in advance for all the helps.

Comment: Show us the full code as the click inside the view holder class will work fine

Comment: updated the adapter class. `onClick` works, but I am not getting the position to the single item details when I click an image in `GridView`

Comment: put final Movies movies = movieItems.get(position); theses codes in onClickListener so that position unarguably be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put **your click listener** inside you **PosterViewHolder** like I did in the below example.

This is the Adapter from my project and my click is working fine for me

```
  /**
     * Created by Rakshit on 7/20/2016.
     */
    public class MyWishListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyWishListAdapter.DataViewHolder> {

        private List<UserWishlist> mList;
        Activity mContext;
        MyWishListFragment fragment;

        public MyWishListAdapter(Activity mContext, MyWishListFragment fragment) {
            mList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }


        @Override
        public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_wishlist_table_row_item, parent, false);
            Constants.setAppFont((ViewGroup) v, parent.getContext());
            DataViewHolder dataView = new DataViewHolder(v);
            return dataView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final DataViewHolder holder, int position) {


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mList.size();
        }

        public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements APIServerResponse {



            public DataViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);


                v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      //View click listener here  
                    }
                });     
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this `@Override
    public PosterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movies_poster_grid_view_item, parent, false);
        return new PosterViewHolder(view);
    }`.

Comment: Put your click listener inside the PosterViewHolder like I did in my DataViewHolder class

Comment: Working on implementing. It keeps getting all the size in the ArrayList. Ans no matter which item I click, I get the first on the list to show. why are you sending Fragment as a parameter in the Adapter class?

Answer (score 1):

Implement on ClickListener

```
public class MoviesGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesGridAdapter.PosterViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

public PosterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
           .......
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           .......
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong try something like this.

```
public class YourClassAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourClassAdapter.YourClassViewHolder>
    implements View.OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<Object> objects;
private View.OnClickListener listener;

public YourClassAdapter(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
    this.objects = objects;
}

@Override
public YourClassViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    return new YourClassViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(YourClassViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Object object = objects.get(position);
    holder.bindObject(object);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(listener != null)
        listener.onClick(view);
}

public static class YourClassViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public YourClassViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void bindObject(Object object) {

    }
}
```

}

And in your Fragment/Activity

```
yourClassAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
            //Do your things
        }
    });
```